# Get full iframe url from command line input and parse as HTML from python variable

Tags: javascript, python, html

I can get the user to input their Google Doc iframe URL and save that as a python variable. When I try to display that variable in HTML with blocking, I just get the html displayed as text on the page. How can I receive the iframe and store it as a Python variable, but then parse it within HTML? Is this possible?

Here is what I mean

```
{% block content %}
<div class="iframe-rwd">{{ config.GDOC_RESUME_EMBED_CODE }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction to how to solve this?

Comment: Is this Jinja2 or Django, or a different templating engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the text as safe for interpolation:

```
<div class="iframe-rwd">{{ config.GDOC_RESUME_EMBED_CODE|safe }}</div>
```

See [Automatic HTML escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping), or if this is a Jinja2 template, the [HTML escaping documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping).

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: For completeness sake, what framework are you using?